# regex search in elasticsearch

Tags: python, regex, elasticsearch

I'm trying to search a list of documents that look like `word+word+word`

Some of these documents have numbers in them like: `word+word+20+word`

Some of these documents have numbers with / in front of them like `word+/2+word`

What would like is to find documents that have numbers in them, but not documents where the numbers have slashes. So I want: `word+20` or `20+word` or `2009063` or `word+/2+word+300`. I don't want `word+word` or `word` or `word+/2` or `/2`.

I have tried using

```
  'query': {
          'filtered': {
                  'query':{
                      'regexp': {
                               'searchterm':'.*[^/][0-9].*'
                              }
                   }
           }
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I've tried escaping it a bunch of different ways and so on, but I keep getting back results with `word+/2+word` which I don't want.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `'.*[0-9].*&~.*/[0-9].*'`. Or `'~(/[0-9])[0-9]~(/[0-9])'`

Comment: It's all about boundary's.

Comment: Lucene regex does not support word boundaries or any anchors, nor lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [COMPLEMENT operator `~`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_optional_operators):

```
'~(/[0-9])[0-9]~(/[0-9])'
```

This regex matches:

- `~(/[0-9])` - any number of characters that are not equal to `/` and a digit, then
- `[0-9]` - matches a digit, and then
- `~(/[0-9])` -  again matches any number of characters that are not equal to `/` and a digit.

Alternatively, use

```
'.*[0-9].*&~.*/[0-9].*'
```

It will match

- `.*[0-9].*` - any line containing a digit
- `&`  - and
- `~.*/[0-9].*` - that does not contain `/` followed with a digit.

Comment: these are not working for me :( could it be that my `+` characters are messing something up?

Comment: So, I *think* this works (based on your suggestion) `'searchterm':'.*[0-9].*~/[0-9]'` does that make sense? I don't seem to be returning *any* lines with `/digit` in my small sample

Comment: @jrubins: No, that does not make sense. `+` is OK o use with Lucene regex engine: *The plus sign "+" can be used to repeat the preceding shortest pattern once or more times.*

Comment: I mean there aren't spaces between words in my documents, only plus signs. So the looks like `foo+bar+baz` not `foo bar baz`. I'm not sure why that would have an effect, so that's why I'm asking. 

As noted above, though, I have a regex that works (I think) based on your original suggestion. I'm going to do some more digging this morning and see if it suits my needs.